# Sakai Installation Done, but connection error

Tags: tomcat, connection, jndi, pool, sakai

I have followed sakai installation as per [this link](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=93028745).

Everything went well. But while starting TomCat I am getting the following error.

Details

> Sakai Version: 10.4
>
> MySql Version: 5.6.16
>
> Tomcat Version: 7.0.65
>
> Maven Version: 3.3.9

Error:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: ValidateObject failed

context.xml

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/sakai" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100"
           maxIdle="30"
           maxWait="10000"
           username="root"
           password=""
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           removeAbandoned="true"
           logAbandoned="true"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakai"/>
```

sakai.properties

```
     username@javax.sql.BaseDataSource=sakaiuser
     password@javax.sql.BaseDataSource=sakaipassword

 ## MySQL settings
     hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
     url@javax.sql.BaseDataSource=java:comp/env/jdbc/sakai
```

Comment: I don't know if this is supposed to work. I haven't seen any ise of context.xml in the Sakai installation guide. Why don't you just specify the url directly in sakai.properties?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already did that and it worked fine. Now I'm stuck at outOfMemory exception. Can you tell me how to increase heap size to run sakai. 
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m *.java works for individual java project. But how to run bunch of projects like sakai with increased heap size

Comment: You can assign to environment variables such as JAVA_OPTS in `setenv.sh`. Put it in the same directory `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` are in.

This will work if you're using `startup.sh` to start Tomcat. If you're using Tomcat as a system service, it may not work. For instance, we do that on Ubuntu, and we have to put the assignments into `/etc/default/tomcat7`.